# How to encode to windows 1252 in Java while writing to the file?

Tags: java, file

If I were to encode the data in windows-1252 format and write it to the file, how to set the content type in java?

Comment: String has a constructor that accepts a charset encoding string for decoding. For encoding, use an OutputStreamWriter`, for which you can provide a charset encoding.

Comment: What would be the charset? As per the below link, should it be cp1252? or windows-1252 where I tried both but of no use. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: The `String` ctor is for _decoding_ bytes.

Comment: @Raghav: You tried both and what happened? Show us your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(yourFile), "windows-1252");
```

Use the typical `Writer` methods to write output to your File (or wrap it, or declare it as `OutputStreamWriter`).

The constructor also accepts a `Charset` instead of the `String` charset name. You can get it like so

```
Charset windows1252 = Charset.forName("windows-1252");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the encoding. According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), you should use `"Cp1252"` when using `java.io` and `java.lang` classes and you should use `"windows-1252"` when using the `java.nio` classes.

So, for instance, you can do this:

```
File file = . . .;
Writer output = new PrintWriter(file, "Cp1252");
```

or, with `java.nio`, this:

```
File file = . . .;
Writer output = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(), "windows-1252");
```

(As Sotirios points out in a comment, you can probably use `"windows-1252"` throughout, despite what the docs say.)

Comment: On windows, putting `"windows-1252"`, Java doesn't complain with `java.io`. Java 7.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yeah, either name probably works. I was just following what the docs say.